# jQuery modal message with text input

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I'm trying to edit the jQuery modal message box by adding an asp:Textbox.
After the user clicks Button1, the dialog appears, the user prompted to input a QtyRun (double). Finally they press Enter.

How can I pass the user input from the dialog to a variable on the aspx form or to an aspx control (like a label)?

Here is my script and aspx code:

```
<script> $(function() {
$('#Button1').click(function() {
    $("#dialog-message").dialog({
     modal: true,
     buttons: {
     Enter: function () {
        $('<%= Label1.Text %>').val($('<%= qtyRunText.Text %>').val());
                $(this).dialog("close");
        }}});
    })
});
```

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<div id="dialog-message" title="Roll# Found!" style="display:none">
<p>
Enter QtyRun: <asp:TextBox ID="qtyRunText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question is why do you need those values in server control.

But, here is how you can do it:

You need the ID of your asp controls:

```
Enter: function () {
        $('#<%=Label1.ID%>').val($('#<%=qtyRunText.ID%>').val());
                $(this).dialog("close");
        }}});
```

This will be more friendly if you set those ID properties on server side:

```
Label1.ID = "asp_mylabel";
qtyRunText.ID = "asp_QtyRunText";
```

in javascript you could call `$('#asp_mylabel')` and `$('#asp_QtyRunText')`

Comment: thanks for the response.

After the user performs a few successful tasks, they will be prompted to enter a value. I think I need these values in server control because I want to later pass them into a sql query, so I can update a table and a gridview later on. The only thing I was planning on using jQueryUI for was the messagebox. If you have a suggestion for a better method, I'd love to know. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @terbubbs then the .ID property is what you need. Read over there for best practices. Good luck.